# Snowflake Credit Calculation during scale up when clusters running in parallel for overlapping period

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How does credit consumed gets calculated during scale up and scale down when queries running on old size cluster as well new queries on new size cluster during the change over.
e.g.  There were 4 queries running on X-Small size taking 12 mins to execute. While these queries running in their 2nd minute, I scaled up warehouse to Small Size and new 2 queries running on Small size for 4 mins and I scale down warehouse again for X-Small size. I have setup 5 mins as auto suspend time. Will the idle time before Auto suspend, charged for X-Small size or Small size ?  How the idle time before auto suspend get charged ?

Answer (score 1):

Before auto-suspend, your warehouse was X-Small, so you should be charged for X-Small.

1) For scale-up, the credits are charged when the servers are provisioned. 
2) The credits are billed for minimum 60 seconds. So when you scale-down after 10 seconds, it will still consume credit for 1 minute.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-considerations.html#how-are-credits-charged-for-warehouses

Answer (score 1):

It should be charged for x-small for 1 min of provisioning plus 5 mins of auto-suspend time - given there is no query executed.
or
It should be charged for x-small for query time(provisioning time & query time) plus 5 mins - given that no additional query was running

Answer (score 1):

A simpler framing might help.

You are billed for what you run.

You are billed for leaving it running idle, so it's ready to run when work arrives.

So if we change instance size, the old instance should shutdown when the last query running on it completes.

So if you where x-small, then small, and then x-small..

If the 3rd instance size (which is the same as the first), and the warehouse is changed to x-small while the original 4 x 12m queries where running. I would assume Snowflake would reallocate the 1st instance as the 3rd instance. But I am open to maybe it not assigning it, just as a "strange edge case". But then the 5 minute idle time should be of the x-small instance.

But if you had picked a third distinct size at the third time, (or if the 3rd instance was not reusing a the first instance), it would also depend if no queries where run on the 3rd instance, I would expect it to have not been started, unless you started it via a resume command. Thus in S3 (the size of the third instance) you could in theory be billed (12m * S1) + (4m * S2) + (5m * S3)

But each instance should not charged "idle time" if there is concern, as they are not the "current instance" being held for future queries.